# Wait for _spPageContextInfo to initialize

Tags: 2013, javascript

What is the **fastest** way to wait/check for `_spPageContextInfo` to be initialized?

I use **AdditionalPageHead** so my scripts are loaded before `_spPageContextInfo` is set.

Here are some alternatives, some I have already tried (single specific system, don't use these numbers as references):

- **`jQuery(document)ready`**: **300ms** - **400ms**.
- **`_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push`**: **300ms** - **400ms**.
- Polling with **`setInterval`**: **10ms** - **30ms**.

Notes: I don't want to use `setInterval`, even though I use `clearInterval`. Despite what some sites say, `ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded`, at least with *sp.js*, can in some instances actually (probably when cached) load before `_spPageContextInfo` is set. I'm skeptical to `defer`-attribute, and I believe `async`-attribute can also load too fast - not very robust.

Comment: Isn't `_spPageContextInfo` defined in the main request along with the HTML? In which case you'd need to wait for it to load?

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn it is simply `<script>_spPageContextInfo={...}</script>`, which is placed later in the markup than my normal `<script src=".."></script>`, which again means it is evaluated at a later time in the DOM - and yes, I must indeed _Wait for _spPageContextInfo to initialize_, but what is the __fastest__ and ultimately the _best_ way to do this?

Comment: I have used the setInterval method sometimes, but not a fan of it. So I'm interested in your outcome here. (PS: @eirikb quak hist ?) :)

Comment: Haha quite the digression, but yes, quak hist and tihlde ;)

Comment: +1 I asked myself the same question. setTimeout was tempting, but I opted for _spBodyOnLoadFunctions. Interesting to hear that ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded is not reliable. Still looking...

Answer (score 7):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getPageContextInfo, "core.js");
function getPageContextInfo() {
    console.log(_spPageContextInfo.systemUserKey);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some brief description about your code. What was your issue and how this code help you solve it.

Comment: Did some research, and if you take a look at the /_layouts/15/core.js file you will see the _spPageContextInfo object is build here. After the core.js finished loading, it executes the NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("core.js") function which triggers all ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded functions set to "core.js". This function is the fastest and cleanest way because it executes right after the _spPageContextInfo object is created.

Comment: @pkmelee337 Are you sure `_spPageContextInfo` is created in _core.js_? I can see `window._spPageContextInfo` is re-assigned, but the initial object seems to be created in the page markup.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Found that out a few months ago, but forgot about this reaction. In your masterpage it is set right after the SharePoint form is created. You won't see it in your masterpage itself, but you can check this in your browser. Altough I am not sure if al property are set there. I personally think only the ones that come from ASP variables, but haven't checked it. Nevertheless if you want to use this property in a javascript file, it's safer to wait for the core.js to make sure it is set, because the page initialization does not fire any events that I'm aware of.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on layout pages like site contents. The `_spPageContextInfo` loads after that triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your script is executed before `_spPageContextInfo` definition in the page markup, I think the easier way is to wait the DOM to be ready to execute your code. `jQuery(document).ready` does exactly that.

In my own tests, checking if the variable is defined with `setInterval` ended up being slightly slower than waiting the DOM to be ready almost all the times when using Google Chrome and jQuery 1.9.1.

So for the sake of simplicity and code maintainability I'd stick with the `jQuery(document).ready` callback.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that `setInterval` is slower, considering jQuery(document).ready will wait until the whole DOM is parsed, while `setInterval` can "jump in there" instantly after `_spPageContextInfo` is defined which is way before the whole DOM is done parsed

Comment: @eirikb here is the code I used to test: http://jsfiddle.net/4myc8965/ - of course I ran it in a SharePoint environment where the HTML markup is a lot heavier. In most times there was a difference of ~10ms between them (e.g. DOM ready = 129ms, interval = 143ms)

Comment: Please note that you have set it to run your demo onLoad

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/4myc8965/3/

Comment: Oh, my bad! :) Anyway, in the test I ran inside a SharePoint environment the code was wrapped inside the head tag. Also, in the code you posted `b` ends up being slightly faster in most of the cases here. Are you getting different results?

Comment: Sometimes I do, yes, I bet if I expand the DOM to be as large as in SharePoint we would see clear differences. This is perhaps a better example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jz0e4uKkP9K4ErnhPcer?p=preview