# Best way to check when _spPageContextInfo is loaded in SP 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to run code right when `_spPageContextInfo` is loaded and want to avoid bad habits using something like `setInterval`. I read on another thread here, you can use this

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {    

}, "core.js");
```

which seems to work on regular pages, but I find that on layout pages like `site contents`, `_spPageContextInfo` loads after that function triggers.

Does anyone know what is the most correct way to make it work for any page?

Thanks

Comment: Refer this link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132416/wait-for-sppagecontextinfo-to-initialize

Comment: That is where I got my current code from, which doesn't seem to work on layout pages.